# vba referencing html elements by xpath

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am a beginner to web scraping with excel vba and need some help.

I am trying to reference an element. If there was an id then I could use getElementByID but sometimes there is no id. I could use getElementByClassName but sometimes there are too many elements of the same class.

Is there some way to refer to an element by xpath?

(I can't post the actual website since there is personal info so let us say this is the html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://google.com">Link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

is there something like ie.document.getElementByXPath.(/html/body/a).click?
I've searched all over the web and can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Comment: I think you might be referring to selecting an element by attribute. For example, getting the element where the `href == 'google.com'`. Am I correct?

Comment: IF (big if) the HTML is valid XHTML, then it's valid XML and can be processed by MSXML libraries, which offer the functionality you want.

Comment: Not xpath but `queryselector[all]` is close to what you're asking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: see this re. querySelector()   arguments 
 https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

this is not meant to be an answer

here is a couple of subs that may give you some ideas

```
Sub google()

    ' add reference: Microsoft XML v6.0

    Const url = "https://www.google.co.in"

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.Send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

    Dim elem As Object
    Set elem = html.getElementsByClassName("ctr-p")               ' HTMLElementCollection
    Debug.Print elem.Length

    Set elem = html.getElementsByClassName("ctr-p")("viewport")   ' HTMLDivElement  <div class="ctr-p" id="viewport">
    Debug.Print elem.Children.Length


    Dim aaa As Object
    Set aaa = elem.getElementsByTagName("div")("hplogo")          ' HTMLDivElement
    Debug.Print aaa.Children.Length
    Debug.Print aaa.outerHTML

End Sub
```

.

```
' add references  Microsoft HTML Object Library
'                 Microsoft Internet Controls

Sub ieGoogle()

    Const url = "https://www.google.co.in"

    Dim iE As InternetExplorer
    Set iE = New InternetExplorer

    iE.Navigate url
    iE.Visible = True

    Do While iE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = iE.Document

    Debug.Print doc.ChildNodes.Length                            ' DOMChildrenCollection
    Debug.Print doc.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes.Item(0).nodeName    ' HEAD
    Debug.Print doc.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes.Item(1).nodeName    ' BODY


    ' for querySelector arguments see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

    Dim elm As HTMLInputElement
    Set elm = doc.querySelector("*")                     ' all elements

    Debug.Print Left(elm.outerHTML, 40)
    Set elm = doc.querySelector("div.ctr-p#viewport")    ' <div class="ctr-p" id="viewport">
    Debug.Print Left(elm.outerHTML, 40)
    Set elm = doc.querySelector(".ctr-p#viewport")       ' <div class="ctr-p" id="viewport">

    Debug.Print Left(elm.outerHTML, 40)
    Debug.Print elm.ChildNodes.Length
    Debug.Print elm.Children.Length


    Set elm = doc.querySelector("#viewport")             ' id="viewport"
    Debug.Print Left(elm.outerHTML, 40)


    Debug.Print elm.ID


    Dim elem As HTMLInputElement
    Set elem = doc.getElementsByClassName("ctr-p")("viewport")



    Debug.Print elem.Children.Length

    Dim aaa As Object
    Set aaa = elem.getElementsByTagName("div")("hplogo")
    Debug.Print aaa.Children.Length
    Debug.Print aaa.outerHTML

    iE.Quit
    Set iE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Excel VBA using Selenium Webdriver (https://www.selenium.dev/).

Webdriver does have a FindElementByXPath method. It has the advantage of providing control of other browser than Internet Explorer, but the disadvantage will be the need to install Selenium in every machine which will run your VBA script.

Here is a walkthrough for installing Selenium and adding its library reference to your project (this was the tutorial I used; it's a pt-br page, but I put into google for automatic translation): https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pt&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomasvasquez.com.br%2Fblog%2Fmicrosoft-office%2Fexcel%2Fvba-interagindo-com-paginas-web-com-o-selenium-webdriver%2F

And here is another quickstart from Coding is Love (it doesn't have the installation walkthrough): https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/