# VBA code that opens links and searches for dynamic keywords in links

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, navbar

I have been doing a lot of research on this, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to resolve my issue. In column N:N, I have hundreds of links that I want to loop through and open. Once the code opens them, I have another worksheet that has a dynamic list of words/phrases that I want the code to reference when searching through each individual link. If the code doesn't find anything in the page, it closes the window and moves on to the next link. If it does find matches (doesn't need to be case sensitive), then it copies all the words/phrases in in corresponding O:O cell each separated by a ";".

Based on my research, I have this snippet of code which will open the links:

```
Dim ie As Object   
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.Visible = True   
Dim x As Integer 
Dim links As Hyperlinks 
Set links = ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks  
For x = 1 To links.Count 
    ie.navigate links.Item(x).Address, Nothing, "_blank"
Next
```

However,  I can't seem to find anything to help me with the last part of this code. I am fairly familiar with VBA, but this is out of my skill set.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You can use xpath to get parts of the page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45702343/3042759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching the keywords or text in web page, You can refer code example below.

```
Sub scraper()

        Dim site As String
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim ie

        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

            Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
            ie.Visible = True

            ie.navigate site

            'idle while ie is busy
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

            With ie.document
                .getelementbyid("UserName").Value = uName
                .getelementbyid("Password").Value = uPass
                .forms(0).submit
            End With
            On Error GoTo error

            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

            For i = 2 To lastRow

                site = Range("A" & i).Value
                ie.navigate site

            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readystate = 4


        msg = ie.document.Body.innerhtml
        If InStr(msg, "Text To Find") = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Not Found"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Found"
       End If
jump:
            Next i
        Exit Sub
error:
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Unknown Error!"
Resume jump


End Sub
```

**This is the sample code, You can try to modify it as per your own requirement.**

Reference:

[Search a web page for a particular text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432917/search-a-web-page-for-a-particular-text)

For copy pasting the values from one cell to another, You can refer link below may give you an idea.

[Best Way To Copy & PasteSpecial Values Only With VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/best-way-to-copy-pastespecial-values-only-with-vba)

Comment: Wow... That is so simple. I'll play with it tonight. Thank you so much!

Comment: If that suggestion helped you to solve your issue than I suggest you to mark the helpful answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It actually pushed me in the right direction. I haven't been able to get VBA to find the text within an element using classname or ID. It's an embedded PDF document within the page (so innerhtml can't see the text). Alternatively, I can have VBA open it as a PDF in IE. I just haven't found a solution to search for text within that.